# Toggle field in custom Arcpy script

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, tool-validation

I've got a script wherein I'd like to toggle (gray out) certain fields, unless a file has been specified.

[image: Script]

In the above image, I'd like Field A, B, and C to only be editable once a file has been selected in Input Worksheet. In updateParameters I've done the following, which doesn't seem to work:

```
  def updateParameters(self):
    if self.params[0].value:
        self.params[1].enabled == True
        self.params[2].enabled == True
        self.params[3].enabled == True
    else:
        self.params[1].enabled == False
        self.params[2].enabled == False
        self.params[3].enabled == False
```

I've tried using `altered` as well, nothing seems to work the way I'd like it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  def updateParameters(self):
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[0].altered:
        self.params[1].enabled = True
        self.params[2].enabled = True
        self.params[3].enabled = True
    elif not self.params[0].value and self.params[0].altered:
        self.params[1].enabled = False
        self.params[2].enabled = False
        self.params[3].enabled = False
```

Two things:

1. Check both if the parameter has value and it has been altered
2. Assign the true and false, not check if it's equivalent or not (= vs ==)

Answer (score 1):

With == you are asking if the enabled parameter is equal to True or False which makes no sense.

What you want to be doing is assigning the parameter True or False, in that case you use a single =.